# generate Unique ID sequence

Tags: php

I want to generate a 7 number Unique ID this is my function to generate.

```
function generate_guid($length){
    $alphabet = '1234567890';
    $tip = array();
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
        $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
        $tip[] = $alphabet[$n];
    }
    return implode($tip);
}
```

Now this is my register function

```
function create_user($email, $name, $country, $password){

    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];    

    $guid = generate_guid(7);

    $active = 0;

    if (email_exists($email)) {
        return false;
    } else 
        if (name_exists($name)) {
            return false;
        } else {

            $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

            $db = dbconnect();

            //MyQuery Code//

            $stmt->close();            

            return true;
        }
}
```

Now I am able to generate and I am able to check if user name and email exist. my issue is how can I check if the guid exist without error and generate new to insert into db ? Or if some one has a better suggestion. the main thing I am trying to accomplish is must be 7 no more lengths long all numbers.

I read about unique ID but it says its not guaranteed, also it has letters. is there a better approach?

I came across this but is aspx [how to generate unique id per user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361137/how-to-generate-unique-id-per-user) would it be possible to generate my function in sequence?

Comment: `rand` is noit very random. From [PHP rand]:(http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) *Caution
This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a cryptographically secure value, consider using random_int(), random_bytes(), or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead.*

Comment: In your function there is a 10% chance the string to become 6 digits long because of the leading zeroe(s). If the length really matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function generate_guid($length){
    $alphabet = '1234567890';
    $tip = array();
    do{
        $uniqueId = substr(str_suffel($alphabet), 0, $length );
        //check uniquekey in database like you check unique username
        //something like that
        $sql = 'select * from tablename where uniqueId = "'.$uniqueId.'"';//if your using PDO, bind accordingly
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }while(mysqli_num_rows($result)); //if no rows, loop will break and you would get uniqu id in $uniqueId variable
return $uniqueId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this to generate unique from int with PHP
https://gist.github.com/Sommerregen/78e5ea478aacfd382323

when hash the number then change $len to 7
you can hash microtime or other incremental number to make sure it is unique.